# How to do an unfold / unwrap animation for cylinder shape in Three.js?

Tags: animation, three.js

I try to do a cylinder unwrap animation for students to better understand the three surfaces of a cylinder.

It should look like this (found on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcqu2yh4jz8)):

[image: cylinder animation unwrap unfold]

1. I can draw both circles (bottom and top) using `THREE.CylinderGeometry`
2. I can draw the lateral surface using `THREE.CylinderGeometry` without filling
3. But how do I do the outer blue animation of the unfolding "rectangle"?!

I have never done an animation with three.js before, so I would also need a suggestion here. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use the youtube video/gif? Licensing issues? Maybe you could just ask for permission? You should know that your question is currently in the close review queue as being "too broad". I think conceptual questions should somewhat be allowed (if they're interesting enough) but others might disagree. As for suggestions on how to learn to animate, use google and look for documentation/tutorials. That's absolutely not SO territory.

Comment: This is an interesting question about a programming technique, it has its place here

Comment: It looks like it's about to be closed though, and no-one has answered it. I think it would help if OP knew *something* about animation and rendering so there was something to start from. Speaking of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739926/best-options-for-animation-in-three-js?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way for this would be to use 3 meshes :

- two `CircleGeometry`-ies for the circles
- one custom `Geometry` for the unwrapping plane

The plane is actually two sets of vertices that represent a line wrapping/unwrapping over a circle. What controls the movement is that angles between each segments are tweened equally. With N being the number of segments, N being even for simplicity, you need to tween this angle from 0 (line state) to 360/N (circle state) on one side, and to -360/N on the other, beginning at the middle (360/N stands for 180/( N/2 ) on each side).

So in your custom `Geometry()` you define vertices and faces. Then you tween them with your favorite tweening library. End each `update` callback with `geometry.verticesNeedUpdate=true;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/2x4Lbvs0/7/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have developped a 3d drawing tool "Geoknecht" and [added the cylinder](http://www.matheretter.de/formeln/geometrie/geoknecht/?draw=zylinder(1%7C1%7C1%204)+zylinder(3%7C-6%7C1%203%200%204%2050%200)+zylinder(1%7C1%7C5%200.5%203%204%2050%200)+zylinder(8%7C-5%7C5%200.2%202%201%2010%200)%5B90%200%200%5D) today - I am able to animate its shape by changing the set text values. This is not the solution for me question above, but a first step. Just need to do the custom Mesh that you mentioned and need an unfold math function to get the right coordinates.

Comment: @Matheretter I have worked on it far longer than I thought :) http://jsfiddle.net/2x4Lbvs0/. I misunderstand the angle conversion from sines/cosines, above pi/2. So it ends in half the tube it should be ! The algorithm to be improved is in the `wrap` and `unwrap` method in the end.

Comment: @Matheretter I hope I don't ping too much. The final version is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2x4Lbvs0/4/). I don't understand where I'm wrong in the maths, in the `update` function. If you solve the issue i'm interested.

Comment: This was an interesting piece of code to write for me, if you need other shape i'd be happy to help.