# Three.js animate in real time

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using three.js and animated some Objects. I animated the object by using the animate() function of three.js. Basically something like that:

```
function animate(){
    object.position.z++;
}
```

Unfortunatlly this is called every rendered frame. So on each device with different framerates the speed of my object is different. Is there a way to make this depending on seconds or miliseconds?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` passes the time since the page was loaded to the callback. I usually prefer to do my math in seconds but the time passed in is in milliseconds so

```
let then = 0;
function animate(now) {
  now *= 0.001;  // make it seconds

  const delta = now - then;
  then = now;

  object.position.z += delta * speedInUnitsPerSecond;

  ...

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

ps: I'm surprised this isn't already on stackoverflow. It probably is somewhere. Certainly requestAnimationFrame has been covered, maybe just not in the context of three.js.

There is this: [Best options for animation in THREE.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739926/best-options-for-animation-in-three-js)

Answer (score 17):

There's also [`THREE.Clock()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Clock) in `three.js`:

```
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var speed = 2; //units a second
var delta = 0;

render();
function render(){
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  delta = clock.getDelta();
  object.position.z += speed * delta;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/pmqkqppy/) example r86

Comment: @JeffProd I mean "speed" :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use TWEEN(a js lib for Three).
This is a tutorial for TWEEN: http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/17/tweenjs-for-smooth-animation/

You can use it very simply:

```js
  new TWEEN.Tween(object.position).to(targetPos, 200).start().onComplete(()=>{
      //Do something when action complete
  });
```